# How to Display Excel DataFrame in tabular format on webpage

Tags: python, json, angularjs, flask

I am developing a web-based Dashboard for that I am using Python as backend Technology and AngularJS as frontend technology.

As I am beginner my first task is to display excel data on Webpage in tabular format

below i written python code which simply reading excel data and converting it into Json format and passing it to html frontend code but seems that output as per my expectation as it showing in Json Format not in Table format.

```
# app.py

from flask import Flask, jsonify
import pandas as pd

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/data')
def get_data():
    # read example Excel file into Pandas dataframe
    df = pd.read_excel('example.xlsx')
    
    # convert dataframe to JSON and return
    return jsonify(df.to_dict(orient='records'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # start Flask server
    app.run(debug=True)
```

here is the frontend code

```
<!-- index.html -->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <title>My Dashboard</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.8.2/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="ExampleCtrl">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Column 1</th>
                <th>Column 2</th>
                <th>Column 3</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="row in data">
                <td>{{row['Column 1']}}</td>
                <td>{{row['Column 2']}}</td>
                <td>{{row['Column 3']}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <script>
        var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
        app.controller('ExampleCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
            $http.get('/data').then(function(response) {
                $scope.data = response.data;
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

expected output is.

| Column 1 | Column 2 | Columns 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0.23 | 0.44 | 0.54 |
| .55 | .4 | .05 |

but getting

```
[
  {
    "Column 1": 0.23,
    "Column 2": 0.44,
    "Column 3": 0.54
  },
  {
    "Column 1": 0.55,
    "Column 2": 0.4,
    "Column 3": 0.05
  }]
```

Answer (score 0):

Add some `CSS` to syle the table. Try this with your `index.html` file, I added some basic table styling.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <title>My Dashboard</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.8.2/angular.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        table {
            width: 100%;
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }

        th, td {
            padding: 8px;
            text-align: left;
            border: 1px solid #ddd;
        }

        th {
            background-color: #f2f2f2;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body ng-controller="ExampleCtrl">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th ng-repeat="col in columnHeaders">{{col}}</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="row in data">
                <td ng-repeat="cell in row">{{cell}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <script>
        var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
        app.controller('ExampleCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
            $http.get('/data').then(function(response) {
                $scope.data = response.data.map(Object.values);
                $scope.columnHeaders = Object.keys(response.data[0]);
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: still showing Json format output, not in tabular format